# jquery selector without using id tag

Tags: jquery

I have this javascript code to find all input elements in a tr

```
var row = button.parentElement.parentElement;
if ((typeof row.id === 'undefined') || (row.id ==='' )) {
    row.id = '__clearsky_formdata';
}
var jsondata = {form: $("#__clearsky_formdata :input").serializeArray(), button: button.innerText };

if (row.id === '__clearsky_formdata') {
    row.id = '';
}
```

just wondering if there is a way of using :input without first constructing an ID, then using $(#  :input) and finally "resetting" the ID back

eg a form of using $(row):input or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to set `id` to get reference of child elements.

You can directly use `row` to create a jQuery object then use methods such as [`.find(selector)`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)/[`.children(selector)`](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

```
$(row) //create a jQuery object
  .find(':input') //get reference to input elements
```

which will be equivalent to

```
$("#__clearsky_formdata :input")
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use [Element querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) in Vanilla JavaScript to get all inputs in the row.**

```
const row = button.parentElement.parentElement;

// Get all input fields from row element
const inputFields = Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('input'));
```

---

**Here's a demo:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  const allInputFields = Array.from(document.querySelector("#myDIV").querySelectorAll('input'));

  const inputFieldValues = allInputFields.map(x => x.value);
  console.log(inputFieldValues);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="myDIV">
    <input type="text" value="2">
    <input type="text" value="3">
  </div>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>

</html>
```